# Which config is applied when number of matched run modes is the same

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

I am using OSGI config files to define configuration for different environments, as specified in [OSGI Configuration](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/configuring/configuring-osgi.html#Resolution%20of%20multiple%20Run%20Modes).  I have configurations for multiple run modes saved in the same repository.  The documentation states

> "If multiple configurations for the same PID are applicable, the
>   configuration with the highest number of matching run modes is
>   applied."

What is the mechanism if multiple configurations for the same PID are applicable and two or more configurations are *tied* for the highest number of matching run modes?  Which one gets applied?

Comment: Good question. I wonder also if it makes a difference whether `/apps/[your-site]/config` is a `sling:Folder` or a `sling:OrderedFolder`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The order or OSGi configs is handled by Apache Sling. Sling has a system that determines priority for [Installable Resources](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/installer/core/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/installer/api/InstallableResource.java) which includes OSGi configurations.

Out of the box, the most powerful component of calculating the priority is the root folder - `/apps` vs `/libs`. See the [JcrInstaller](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/installer/providers/jcr/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/installer/provider/jcr/impl/JcrInstaller.java) and its configuration in your localhost at http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/org.apache.sling.installer.provider.jcr.impl.JcrInstaller. The difference between the `/libs` and `/apps` "points" is large at 100 (`{"/libs:100", "/apps:200"}`).

After the root priority is determined, the Sling run modes are added up. See [org.apache.sling.installer.provider.jcr.impl.FolderNameFilter#getPriority](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/installer/providers/jcr/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/installer/provider/jcr/impl/FolderNameFilter.java). Each run mode is valued at 1 "point" regardless of order. For example, at this point if you have run modes `alpha` and `bravo`, `config.alpha.bravo` is equal to `config.bravo.alpha`.

Priority then looks at certain things such as the Resource State and whether the resource is installed or not and whether the resource is a `SNAPSHOT` version which probably will apply more to bundles than configurations in your project. Ultimately, the comparison of the OSGi configs will come down to a lexicographically string comparison of the URLs. Going back to our example, at this point, `config.alpha.bravo` has a higher priority than `config.bravo.alpha`.

Should the OSGi configs be lexicographically equal, the final comparison is an MD5 hash of the Digest. See [org.apache.sling.installer.provider.jcr.impl.ConfigNodeconverter#computeDigest](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/installer/providers/jcr/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/installer/provider/jcr/impl/ConfigNodeConverter.java).

See the full comparison function at [org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.RegisteredResourceImpl#compare](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/installer/core/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/installer/core/impl/RegisteredResourceImpl.java).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer with links!